# Xcode/iPhone: Remember login information + next window

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I have made a login app which connects to a mysql database. When signed in I want the app to take me to a new screen where it says ex: "Hi Helle", using the information I just signed in with. Where do I start? The login function works.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to store your login session somewhere. When you successfully log in, you should probably get some sort of token or something that says "I'm logged in as this user". Store it somewhere, probably with Keychain(https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security) or NSUserDefaults. Then you can access it from anywhere in your app.

If you don't need to persist it, just pass the login information around the app keeping it in memory.